# d3 tree count all children

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, tree

I have a d3 tree based on the following...

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

How would I get a count of all the children?  I have tried this however it counts all the rows in the tree...

```
$(".tree_badge").text(tree.links(nodes).length);
```

So in the example it should count all the children where children would be the orange coloured rows in the tree (like those in cluster, graph, etc).

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually had a similar problem where I had to grab all of the descriptions from a tree below a particular node. The answer in my case and yours is to recursively descend the tree and do something on the way down. Should look something like this.

```
var count;

function count_leaves(node){
    if(node.children){
        //go through all its children
        for(var i = 0; i<node.children.length; i++){
            //if the current child in the for loop has children of its own
            //call recurse again on it to decend the whole tree
            if (node.children[i].children){
                count_leaves(node.children[i]);
            }
            //if not then it is a leaf so we count it
            else{
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: if you want to count all of the nodes below your node and not just the ones at the end of the tree, just add a count++ inside the if as well as the else.

Comment: What is `recurse`? Did you mean `count_leaves`?

Comment: yes, sorry. I called it recurse when I wrote it the frist time. I changed it for this post

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `leaves` method

[image]

Since I've come here from google looking for `how to optimally count each children's descendants`, the solution would be

[image]