# D3js text too small

Tags: d3.js, text, tree

I made a simple tree structure and displayed it using D3.js. When nodes become too many, it's impossible to see any text.

[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm4Bp.png) [Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py5TL.png)

I could make an image out of the svg, then render it instead of displaying the tree by d3js and finally using a magnifier to zoom in. I don't know if it can actually work; is there a better and working way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to render it to an image, just make the `svg` [zoom and pannable](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033).

Comment: @Mark I like it, make it an answer and I will accept it. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I would recomend placing your lable below the nodes rather than to the right as that will win you some space back but that won't really solve your problem.

I would recomend either making your tree [colapse by node](https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950)

or defining the space between the nodes as a function of how many children there are. For this, you will need to recursively count the children in your tree. You can see how to do that in an answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513923/d3-tree-count-all-children/38514920#38514920)

There are likely other solutions but those are the two that jump out at me as the best.